# $325$ as sum of $2$ squares three ways

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I checked  on a simple way using an excel sheet, and I believe I found $325$ to be the lowest natural number which can be expressed as a sum of two square in $3$ different ways $(1,18), (6,17)$ and $(10,15)$ but is this also true?

Comment: Yes, 325 is the smallest according to this: https://oeis.org/A025313

Comment: note: $325=5^2\times 13$ is the smallest number that factors as $p^2q$ where $p,q$ are distinct primes of the form $4k+1$

Comment: Here is a [MathWorld article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SumofSquaresFunction.html) on the topic.